# DS18B20 with NodeJS on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, command-line, serial-port, temperature

I'm trying to read temperatures into NodeJS (or command-line program) app on Windows with DS18B20 thermometers connected to serial port.

There are some apps, but I can't use them (Digitemp - no support for Windows, Logtemp - it doesn't communicate with NodeJS.

Is there any possible way to read temperatures directly in NodeJS from serial port or from command-line program? 
There are lots of tutorials and libraries for Arduino, but nothing for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to read from a serial port with Node.js.  There are plenty of NPM modules for it.  Is your problem with reading from the serial port, or parsing the protocol?

Comment: @Brad Parsing the OneWire protocol.